# It is possible that display pictures in MPandroidchart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Now I`m using MPandroidchart. and my chart is showing sensing data.

also the camera is taking pictures when the data value of chart is overflow

it`s standard value point.

At this moment, I want to display pictures that already taken when I click

overflow point using markerview.

It is possible that display pictures in MPandroidchart?

thank you for watching.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Teocci, some of mistake my question. I don`t want code-writing service. I just know that possiblilty of my question.

Comment: According to the Github repository, this library has a class called [MarkerView](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/MarkerView.java). This class may show a tooltip. And in the example you can see that you may create a custom marker view layout and add an image as a background of the layout. If you think is what you need let me know to add a complete solution.